# Will e-mails with reply-to addresses from domains you haven't the right to send from be blocked?

Tags: security, blocking

According to [this source](https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=435858#p1753993), you can only use from or reply-to from domains you have the right to send from, otherwise you'll find yourself getting blocked.
I thought, as long as the from-address is from a domain you have the right to send from, you are free to choose your reply-to domain.
Could someone confirm the above source and maybe some other, more profound internet sources that provide some background?

Comment: What you describe is a form of email relaying and the emails will most likely be blocked. I use a portable sender to get around this.

Comment: Interesting! What is a "portable sender"?

Comment: I use Mail.com's Sender SMTP and it works in all locations with all ISPs. I have an account with them. The key advantage is any ISP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing is called email relaying.  It is not permitted in most cases because spammers would have a heyday if it were.

I travel around and with my own ISP, if I am on a different ISP, then I cannot send email and have to wait.

I solved this for myself by using the Mail.com SMTP server. I have an account with them and it works everywhere I go including overseas.

Here is a good Microsoft Article on Relaying Denied (as you has asked)

[Email relaying](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/i-receive-a-550-553-or-relay-prohibited-error-when-sending-email-messages-65b494a4-0a15-433e-829f-e73651e0245e)

> The exact error message might vary, depending on your Internet service
> provider (ISP). Some ISPs might not return an error message when they
> detect outgoing messages as unsolicited commercial email. In these
> cases, your message might appear to be sent normally — it leaves your
> Outlook Outbox and appears in your Sent Items — but it's never
> actually delivered to the recipient.
>
> Your message was rejected because the SMTP (outgoing) email server did
> not recognize you as an authorized user

.